# Filter/match on an array against nested property - multiple filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, filtering

I have a simple select. The select returns a string value e.g. "foo". I then match the string value against all entries in a list. Only the entries that match return. `entry.eventType.description === this.ngxValue; // "foo" === "foo" returns true`

**e.g single select**

```
// this.ngxValue = "foo"

private multiEventTypeFilter(entry) {
    if (this.ngxValue === 'Any') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return entry.eventType.description === this.ngxValue;
    }
}
```

**multi select**

I've now changed my select to allow for multi selections. This now returns an array that's made up of all selected values e.g. `["foo", "bar", "car"]`. So now I want to return all entries that match ANY value in that array. `this.ngxValue` is no longer a single string but an array with multiple strings. The below is what is desired...

```
entry.eventType.description === this.ngxValue; // "foo" === ["foo", "bar", "car"] returns true
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return this.ngxValue.indexOf(entry.eventType.description) !== -1;
```

Sorry all. I found the answer straight away. I will post here but if there are alternatives then please feel free to show.

Answer (score 2):

Although [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is a straight forward way of fulfilling the requirement, there's another alternative [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).
Since you are looking for other alternatives, mentioning here so that it could be helpful anytime later

Below is the example how to use `Array.prototype.some()`

```js
let data = ["foo", "bar", "car"]

console.log(data.some(d => d === "foo"))
```

And for your requirement, below is the way

```
return this.ngxValue.some(val => val === entry.eventType.description);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
return this.ngxValue.includes(entry.eventType.description);
```

This will return `true` if the value is present in the array and `false` otherwise.